# Many "bad nonce received or getnonce not called" in mongo log

Tags: authentication, mongodb, nonce

Hi all,

Now I use mongo as my database. I found my mongo connection is auto-reset or failed sometimes. Then I found some strange message in my mongo log file, which is

```
auth: bad nonce received or getnonce not called. could be a driver bug or a security attack. db:User
```

I googled it, but it seemed few users had encounted this problem, and I only found the source code in github with link *https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/db/security_commands.cpp*. From the code, the client sends **user_name, use_password, nonce** to the server for the authentication, the log message is caused by the difference between the nonce sent by the client and distributed by the server.

Is there anything wrong with my mongo driver? Anybody has encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error as well, when I was using mongodb-2.0.2 and java-driver2.7.3. 
It's a single mongodb server for development with `--auth` option opened.

I understand it's caused by authentication in multi-threading:

```
DB db = m.getDB(dbName);
if(!db.isAuthenticated())
{
        boolean pass = db.authenticate(name, pwd.toCharArray());
        if(!pass)
            throw new Exception("User " + name + " authentication failed for db " + dbName + "!");
}
```

From the server side, before one auth request is accomplished, another thread sent a new request, which causes the first one to be overriden.

After adding `synchronized` to this method, it never appeared again.